# getting zend tools to rename actions

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, rename, zend-tool

so we can use zend tools to create actions, controllers, etc., and it will do the dirty work ...

but then what if you want to rename said actions, controllers? is there a way to do this without manually changing all the names in various files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment, it isn't possible - as same as deleting actions, controllers and so on.

Answer (score 0):

No ways. You should rename stuff manually. Type **zf --help** to see avalaible console actions.